# How to differentiate the electric field on the surface of a conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, definition, vector-fields

Given a conductor, let $n$ be the unit normal field of the surface and $E$ the magnitude of the electric field. How to understand the expression
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial n}$$
on the surface of the conductor? The usual meaning of such an expression would be "the directional derivative of $E$ in direction $n$". However, if I understand things correctly, the electric field is in general not differentiable at points on the surface of a conductor (at least not differentiable in the sense of classical differential calculus). So, what does this expression mean? What is the definition?

**Background:** This expression appears in exercise 1.11 of Jackson's $\textit{Classical Electrodynamics}$ from chapter 1 and I am trying to work on it. However, I am NOT asking for a solution of that exercise.

**My ideas so far**: The expression could make sense in differential geometry if we view the surface as a 2 dimensional manifold and then differentiate in local coordinates. Another idea might be something like "distributional derivative". Both ideas are just speculations and it might happen that the meaning is still something completely different...

Comment: Probably just take the one-sided derivative https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/One-sided_derivative

Comment: I do not really understand what this should mean here. In case of a conductor, the electric field on the surface is a multiple of the normal field but the normal field is in general only defined on the surface...

Comment: Here's an example, specializing to a sphere. $\hat{n} = \hat{r}$ and $E \sim 1/r^2$ outside the conductor. Then at the conductor, we have
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial E}{\partial r} |_{r=R}= \frac{-2}{R}.$$
Which is also equal to
$$-\left(\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R}\right)$$
where in the differentiation I computed the one-sided derivative of $E\sim 1/r^2.$

Answer (score 3):

Diffycue's comment has the right idea. Yes, the E-field is discontinuous at the surface, but we may formally express the E-field just outside point $\vec r$ on the surface of the conductor as

$$\vec E_s(\vec r)= \lim_{h\rightarrow{0^+}}\vec E(\vec r+h\hat n)$$
where $\hat n$ is the outward unit normal vector. Then,

$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial n} = \hat n\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow{0^+}}\frac{\vec E(\vec r+h\hat n) -\vec E_s(\vec r)}{h}. $$